# initrd or ramfs for SLES as /

Tags: suse, initrd, initramfs, sles

I would like to boot a SLES and run it out of a ramdisk.
I would like to setup machines so that they start PXE boot and as part of the PXE boot process they pull across an image that is the root filesystem and then boot this.

Has anyone done this or similar yet?

My thinking is that the `initrd` is almost what i want to have although far too small and short on features. So i did a minimal install and then did a cpio of this to create my own custom `initd`. (This is about 350M, which although big is fine for this purpose).

It has trouble booting up at the point when it tries to `fsck` the `/dev/shm/root`. What is the correct way to stop this happening (I tried by setting in `/etc/fstab`, but no good).
As next option I set a sysconfig file to force READONLYROOT and this got me booting the init process as far as the point where it switches to `/etc/init.d/rc3.d` but now I can't get it to go further.

Any advice or ideas or if someone else has done this they that would all be great.

PS. Setup is big nodes with 1TB RAM and I don't want to have local filesystem for OS and the alternative is to have NFS server the root filesystem, but I don't want the NFS traffic so RAM disk seems like good option.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is specific about `/dev/shm/root` fsck. Thus you should put that in the title of your question in order to get the attention of the right people.

Comment: i have now edited the K06boot.rootfsck to add rootfs as an exception and therefore avoid the fsck of / so this part is now good.

My problem now is that when the boot process is finished with /etc/init.d/boot.d and is about to step into /etc/init.d/rc3.d it crashes.

Comment: You should not make that a comment but edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made good progress.

I edited the file /etc/init.d/boot.d/boot.rootfsck to add ramfs as a filesystem type exception to the fsck process. (line 79).

```
        aufs|tmpfs|afs|cifs|nfs|novell|smb|ramfs|UNKNOWN*) MAY_FSCK=0 ;;
```

After doing this it is no longer necessary to have sysconfig with READONLYROOT.

After doing this i setup pxelinux.cfg to have a boot line as follows:

```
LABEL SLES11 InMemory OS
  KERNEL suseBig/vmlinuz-3.0.74-0.6.8-default
  APPEND initrd=suseBig/suseImage rdinit=/sbin/init
  TIMEOUT 100
```

The file suseImage is a cpio archive of the whole root filesystem of a working install of SLES, but with a modified /etc/fstab line for root. (i had to build the CPIO archive by accessing this working SLES environment from another working OS (on another disk))

```
rootfs /                  rootfs       defaults        0 0
```

Once this is all in place the node boots up happily and i now have a working ramdisk version of SLES that boots across the network via PXE. (so it is slow to boot, but after that it has no network traffic for OS). It has no persistence, but i solve that for my case in the application layer.